# Number of children explodes after filtering on child value

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model (Track) with children (Rank). That can be described (simplified) as:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField('Unique ID', max_length=100, 
    primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField('Track title', max_length=100)
    artist = models.CharField('Artist name', max_length=100)

class Rank(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    trackid = models.ForeignKey(Track, related_name='rank')
    cdate = models.DateField("Date", blank=True, null=True)
```

When doing this:

```
track_list = Track.objects.filter(Q(artist__icontains=query) | 
Q(title__icontains=query)) \
.annotate(children=Count('rank'))

for track in track_list:
    print(track.children)
```

The number of children per track are all close to 100 (e.g 65,78,95) and that is correct.

But when I narrow the queryset further down by applying another filter and a needed annotation:

```
track_list = track_list.distinct() \
.filter(rank__cdate__year=filterquery) \
.annotate(entrydate=Min('rank__cdate')) \
.annotate(children=Count('rank'))

for track in track_list:
    print(track.children)
```

The number of children explodes to several thousands per track.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably by joining you get the `Rank` models multiple times. Try adding a `distinct=True` to the `Count` as follows:

```
track_list = track_list.distinct() \
    .filter(rank__cdate__year=filterquery) \
    .annotate(entrydate=Min('rank__cdate')) \
    .annotate(children=Count('rank', distinct=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.annotate(children=Count('rank', distinct=True))`

Comment: Thanx! but I'm going to accept the answer of @jgadelange. Since he/she was the first caller.